# Right dynamic class generation using Moose::Meta::Class or Class::MOP::Class

Tags: perl, oop, code-generation, moose

I'd like to implement simple method chaining, for that methods must return objects. Since my code is using Moose already and my future classes are almost empty and return only one attribute with instance of another class I decided to generate them programmatically with [Moose::Meta::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Meta::Class) (that is subclass of [Class::MOP::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::MOP::Class)). First time working with Moose metaclasses so I wrote a simple code to try:

```
package Cat;
use Moose;


package Generator;
use Moose;

sub generate {

    Class::MOP::Class->create(
       'Siberian' => (
           methods => {
                echo => sub { print 'yeah!' }
            }
       )
    );

    Class::MOP::Class->create(
       'Tiger' => (
           attributes   => [
               Class::MOP::Attribute->new('Siberian' => (
                default => sub { require Siberian; Siberian->new; }
               )),
           ],
       )
    );

    Cat->meta->add_attribute(Class::MOP::Attribute->new(
        Tiger => (
            default   => sub { require Tiger; Tiger->new }
        )
    ));

    print "Generation done!\n";

}

generate();


package main;
use Generator;

my $a = Cat->new;
warn  $a->Tiger->Siberian->echo; # must print 'yeah!' but prints Can't locate object method "new" via package "Tiger" at dynamic.pl line 33
```

Instead of expected `yeah!` in output I see

> Can't locate object method "new" via package "Tiger" at dynamic.pl
>   line 33

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Who will respond to constructor creation?

Another way is using of metaclass variables directly.

https://gist.github.com/akzhan/421579163dfc86f570809f50d239800f